# Получить асинхронный ввод из консоли в Python

Tags: python, многопоточность, асинхронность

Я делаю программу на Python, которая при работе может получить вход от терминала.

Например, во время выполнения какого-либо процесса он может управляться асинхронно из терминала и не останавливаться для пользовательского ввода.

Как это сделать в Python?

Comment: Запустить два потока, в одном работать, в другом ждать пользовательский ввод

Comment: @andreymal такое не работает

Comment: Работает, лично делал неоднократно

Comment: @andreymal тогда приведи пример такого кода

Comment: https://pastebin.com/AZk9w8xb

Comment: @andreymal любой вывод сбрасывает ввод текста + мне нужно, что бы сам код выполнялся в основном процессе

Comment: Подстройка вывода под ввод это совершенно отдельная проблема, не имеющая отношения к асинхронной работе. Пример асинхронной работы я показал выше, и всё это происходит в основном и единственном процессе.

Comment: @andreymal К примеру, команда для приложения очень длинная и вдруг оно выводит какую-либо информацию на экран. Что тогда - команда сброшена. А что если вывод идёт каждые 1-2 секунда - как команду будет ввести?

Comment: @Dmitry Как обычно. Вывод никак не влияет на ввод.

Comment: @МихаилМуругов могу предоставить видео запись, где ввод сбрасывается из-за вывода

Comment: что делает основной процесс? он асинхронный или блокирующий. это много мелких задач или одна большая?

Comment: @eri В основном процессе присутствуют асинхронные методы

Comment: тогда вешай asyncio ридер на stdin и всёго делов

Comment: @eri а как это сделать(напиши как ответ с примером кода)?

Comment: @Dmitry вы не видео предоставьте, а код)

Comment: @eri код взят из ответа

Answer (score -1):

```
import asyncio
import sys
import os

startstop = asyncio.Event()

async def main():
    print('wait start')
    await startstop.wait()
    while startstop.is_set():
        print('.',end='',flush=True)
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

def reader_cb(infile, task):
    cmd = infile.readline().strip()
    print(repr(cmd))
    if cmd == 'start':
        startstop.set()
    elif cmd == 'stop':
        startstop.clear()
    elif cmd == 'kill':
        startstop.clear()
        task.cancel()

loop=asyncio.get_event_loop()
# task = loop.create_task(main())
loop.add_reader(sys.stdin.fileno(), reader_cb, sys.stdin, task)
# loop.run_forever()
asyncio.run(main())
```

<s>На Виндовс не умеет select не на сокетах.
https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/asyncio-eventloops.html#asyncio.SelectorEventLoop</s>

Переключите на ProactorEventLoop перед основным кодом.

```
import asyncio, sys

if sys.platform == 'win32':
    loop = asyncio.ProactorEventLoop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
```

А хотя читаем дальше...

> add_reader() and add_writer() are not supported

Попробуйте uvloop:

$ pip install uvloop

```
import asyncio
import uvloop
uvloop.install()

async def main():
    # Main entry-point.
    ...
...
asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: OSError: [WinError 10038] Сделана попытка выполнить операцию на объекте, не являющемся сокетом

Comment: на линуксе всё работает нормально) windows не умеет select на пайпах? может там надо эвент луп настроить