# Python Asincio взаимодействие через stdin и stdout

Tags: python-3.x, input, async-await, асинхронность, asyncio

Есть у меня программа, которая играет, скажем, в крестики-нолики. Она принимает данные в input() и печатает следующий ход. Примерно вот так:

```
while True:
  current_data = input()
  result = calc(current_data)
  print(result)
```

Хочу написать программу, которая сталкивает две такие программы и заставляет их играть друг с другом. Скорее всего это функция asyncio.create_subprocess_shell. Пытаюсь читать документацию, но пока понимаю что ничего не понимаю. В javascript оно как-то попроще было на коллбеках.

Наверняка кто-то уже писал что-то подобное, подскажите, пожалуйста!

Comment: виндовс или линукс?

Comment: Мне, в общем, без разницы, но для простоты возьмем классический линукс. Даже версию питона могу любую поставить =)

Comment: У винды ограничение что она может делать select() только на сокетах. Ввод вввод на пайпы там нужно делать на тредах - асинкио не поможет. Надо конечно попробовать uvloop. Он не на селекте, может прокатит

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1131788/16574